# Need help getting output to show using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to show the output (sum, difference, product, quotient) of the 2 numbers in the span below the form. I have tried many variations but cannot get the sum and etc to show at all. Please help I'm a Javascript noob!!! Thanks!

```
 function calculate() {
'use strict';

// Read the first text box and convert to a float
var input = document.getElementById('number1').value;
var number1 = parseInt(input);


var input = document.getElementById('number2').value;
var number2 = parseInt(input);


// Calculations 
sum = number1 + number2;
difference = number1 - number2;
product = number1 * number2;
quotient = number1 / number2;

// Display the results in relevant spans
document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
document.getElementById('difference').value = difference;
document.getElementById('product').value = product;
document.getElementById('quotient').value = quotient;


return false;

} 


function init() {
'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
} 
window.onload = init;
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
    <fieldset>
        <div><label for="number1">Number 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" required>
        </div>
        <div><label for="number2">Number 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" required>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<span id="sum"></span><br />
<span id="difference"></span><br /> 
<span id="product"></span><br />
<span id="quotient"></span><br />
```

Comment: Nearly there! You've asked for the `.value` attribute of the 4 target divs - thing is, divs don't have a `.value` attribute. Use innerHTML instead. E.g: `document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign value to a span tag, we need to use `innerHTML` property, not `value`.

```
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
document.getElementById('difference').innerHTML = difference;
document.getElementById('product').innerHTML = product;
document.getElementById('quotient').innerHTML = quotient;
```

And Change

```
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm" onsubmit="return calculate()">
```

You just have to invoke the `calculate` function on form's submission.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! The innerHTML did it! It only works in Firefox though. Do you know why?

Comment: If it doesnt work on chrome, open the page and press `F12` key and see if it shows any errors.